# Needs help filtering posts on Contentful using javascript for a Next.js site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, contentful

I'm feeding a Next.js blog with Contentful and querying for some posts at the frontpage. And even tho I can `.filter()` featured posts by using a simple boolean value I can't seem to understand how could I fetch posts for matching categories within my post structure.

Here's a sample of what my query for featured posts looks like.

```
{posts.filter((posts) => (posts.fields.postDestaque)) // it filters posts that have 'postDestaque' false or null
   .slice(0, 6) // cuts off the excess 
   .map((post, i) => { // maps the posts and returns the component
   
   return <PostVertical key={i} post={post} noCats={noCats} noData={noData} />
})}
```

The categories are held within an array with objects of fields that contain names and slugs for each one like this:

```
0:
  fields:
    categorias: Array(2)
      0:
        fields:
          nome: "Main Category"
          slug: "main-category"
      1:
        fields:
          nome: "Other Category"
          slug: "other-category"
```

I'm a front-end guy so I don't know how to filter the posts for a category. I thought .find() could work, but it would only return the object that matches with it, so, the category itself. Plus I'm not understanding how I could reach for a second array and test the post object itself. Is there another method I could use instead of filter or find?

Thanks a lot for any comments on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its an array you're trying to filter, you can get away with just using `.filter` and `.some` I added small snippet below, but you just want to make sure that you return a boolean once you find the category want to filter in, `.some` does that.

```js
posts.filter(post => post.fields.categorias.some(categoria => categoria.slug === 'main-category'));
```

```js
const posts = [{
    fields: {
      categorias: [{
          noma: 'Main Category',
          slug: 'main-category',
        },

        {
          noma: 'Other Category',
          slug: 'other-category',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    fields: {
      categorias: [{
          noma: 'Main Category1',
          slug: 'main-category1',
        },

        {
          noma: 'Other Category1',
          slug: 'other-category1',
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    fields: {
      categorias: [{
          noma: 'Main Category2',
          slug: 'main-category2',
        },

        {
          noma: 'Other Category2',
          slug: 'other-category2',
        },
      ],
    },

  },
];

const byCategory = category => post => post.fields.categorias.some(categoria => categoria.slug === category);
const byMainCategory = byCategory('main-category');
const filteredByCategorias = posts.filter(byMainCategory)

console.log("filtered by categorias", filteredByCategorias)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. Not only helped me with this specific issue but taught me how to deal with such things in javascript. I'm updating other parts of my code here.